# Diferencia entre variable de tabla y tabla temporal en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Al parecer, hay dos maneras de crear una tabla temporal en SQL-Server:

Con un variable de tabla (*table variable*)

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (Col1 INT, Col2 INT)
```

o con una tabla temporal (*temporary table*)

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (Col1 INT, Col2 INT)
```

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre ellas?

---

Pregunta original: [What's the difference between a temp table and table variable in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server)

Comment: En la definición de la pregunta dices, "Al parecer hay dos maneras de crear una tabla temporal" y luego mencionas una variable de tabla, que se entiende que es temporal en el sentido que de solo funciona en el ámbito de ejecución de por ejemplo un store procedure, pero que conceptualmente no es una tabla temporal. Creo que deberías ceñirte al título, y no generar confusión, eliminando el prólogo que te menciono.

Comment: La verdad creo que esta respuesta publicada en DBA.SE es mucho más completa: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Existen algunas diferencias entre las tablas temporales (#tmp) y variables (@tmp), aunque el uso de tempdb no es uno de ellos, tal como se expone en el enlace de abajo MSDN.

Como regla general, para volúmenes pequeños y medianos de datos y escenarios de uso simples tu debes utilizar las variables de tabla. (Esta es una pauta demasiado amplia por supuesto muchas de excepciones - véase más adelante y después de artículos.)

Algunos puntos a considerar al momento de elegir entre ellas:

> - Las tablas temporales son en realidad tablas por lo que se pueden hacer cosas como CREATE INDEXes, etc. Si manipulas grandes cantidades
>     de datos para las que el acceso por índice será más rápido que las
>     tablas temporales, estas son una buena opción.
> - Las variables de tabla pueden tener índices mediante el uso de restricciones PRIMARY KEY o UNIQUE. (Si quieres un índice no único
>     basta con incluir la columna de clave primaria (primary key) como la
>     última columna en la restricción única. Si usted no tiene una columna
>     única, puede utilizar una columna de identidad.) SQL 2014 contiene
>     índices no únicos también.
> - Las variables de tabla no participan en las transacciones, registro o de bloqueo (logging or locking). Esto significa que son más rápidas,
>     ya que no requieren la sobrecarga, pero por el contrario no te dan
>     esas características. Así por ejemplo, si desea restaurar (ROLLBACK) a
>     medio camino a través de un procedimiento, entonces las variables de
>     tabla pobladas durante esa transacción seguirán estando pobladas!
> - Tablas temporales podrían dar lugar a Stored Procedures recompilados. Las variables de tabla no.
> - Puedes crear una tabla temporal utilizando SELECT INTO, que puede ser más rápido para escribir (bueno para un ad-hoc de consulta) y
>     puede permitir  lidiar con el cambio de tipos de datos a través del
>     tiempo, ya que no es necesario definir la estructura de su tabla
>     temporal por adelantado.
> - Puedes pasar variables de tabla volviendo de funciones, lo cual permite encapsular y reutilizar la lógica mucho más fácil (por
>     ejemplo, hacer una función para dividir una cadena en una tabla de
>     valores con algún delimitador arbitrario).
> - Uso de las variables de tabla dentro de las funciones definidas por el usuario (user-defined functions) permite a aquellas funciones que
>     se utilizarán más ampliamente (ver documentación de CREATE FUNCTION
>     para más detalles). Si escribes una función debes utilizar las
>     variables de tabla sobre tablas temporales a menos que haya una
>     necesidad imperiosa.
> - Ambas variables de tabla y tablas temporales son almacenadas en tempdb. Pero las variables de tabla (desde el 2005) por defecto al
>     "collation" de las bases de datos actuales en comparación con tablas
>     temporales que tienen el "collation" predeterminado de tempdb
>     ([referencia](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx)). Esto significa que se deben evitar detalles de
>     "Collation" si se utilizan tablas temporales y tu "collation" es
>     diferente a la de la tempdb, causando problemas si desea comparar los
>     datos en la tabla temporal con los datos en la base de datos.
> - Tablas temporales globales (## tmp) son otro tipo de tabla temporal disponible para todas las sesiones y usuarios.

Algunas lecturas adicionales:

[Gran respuesta de Martin Smith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server/16386#16386) en dba.stackexchange.com

MSDN FAQ acerca de la diferencia entre los dos: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/305977

artículo en el blog MDSN: http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2008/03/30/sql-server-table-variable-vs-local-temporary-table.aspx

Artículo: http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid87_gci1267047,00.html#

Comment: si no fuera mucha molestia puedes dejar de poner la frase "actualizando continua" al final de cada actualización parcial. Simplemente síguela editando sin ningun tipo de aviso

Comment: Claro que sí, perfecto!

Comment: *Pero las variables de tabla por defecto al "collation" de las bases de datos actuales en comparación con tablas temporales que tienen el "collation" predeterminado de tempdb*. Esta frase no se entiende muy bien, parece dicha por el presidente de España. ¿Podrías aclararla un poco?

Comment: El párrafo que se refiere al uso del _Collation_ es parcialmente incorrecto ya que se traduce la expresión "you should be aware" como "se deben evitar detalles". Esto es incorrecto, no es que se deban evitar detalles sino que hay que prestar atención o tener cuidado ya que el collation podría ser diferente entre tempdb y las bases de datos. En el próximo comentario mi sugerencia para la traducción.

Comment: Ambas son almacenadas en tempdb. Pero las variables de tabla (desde el 2005) usan de manera predeterminada el "collation" de la base de datos actual, en cambio las tablas temporales usan el "collation" predeterminado de tempdb. Esto significa que hay que prestar atención (tener cuidado/estar al tanto) con los posibles problemas de collation si se utilizan tablas temporales y el "collation" utilizado es diferente a la de la tempdb, pudiendo causar problemas si desea comparar los datos en la tabla temporal con los datos en la base de datos.

Answer (score 2):

En la practica luego de prueba y error para obtener mayor velocidad, a nivel general debería de:

1. Use tablas de variables `@tabla` para cuando los datos sean pocas columnas y filas, ej. max. 10 columnas y menos de 10.000 registros, y no tiene que hacer cambios (`update`, `delete`, `insert`) a la tabla. Recuerde que se almacena en memoria RAM, por tanto dependerá de su servidor.
2. Use tablas temporales `#tabla` o `##tabla` (globales, es decir en todas las sesiones), cuando tenga miles de registros y/o necesite actualizar datos en la tabla. A veces cuando la cree, si tiene mas de 10.000 filas, es muy eficiente crear un *indice primario* `PK`, y/o un indice optimizado para una consulta sobre los datos.
3. Pruebe con ambas opciones y mida en rendimiento, según el caso le dará la respuesta de que le es mas eficiente para su caso particular, es relativamente fácil cambiar el resultado de un `select into @mitabla` a `select into #mitabla`.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (Col1 INT, Col2 INT)
```

Desde la versión SQL SERVER 2008, se usa la variable tipo TABLA, solo están vigente durante la ejecución del bloque de código.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (Col1 INT, Col2 INT)
```

Estas tablas son creadas en la base de datos tempdb, en la carpeta llamada Temporary Tables. si cerramos la conexión actual, esta tabla se eliminará.

Las variables tipo tabla solo están vigentes durante menor tiempo, solo durante el bloque de código en ejecución.

Existen tablas temporales [locales y globales](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1556/differences-between-sql-server-temporary-tables-and-table-variables/) que solo están vigentes durante la conexión o conexiones que fueron abiertas.

Answer (score 0):

Desde una humilde opinion en la practica profesional, esperando les ayude ...

**1)** Con la tabla como variable y una cantidad de datos de 20, 000 registros empezo a inflarse mi `temdb` =>
`DECLARE @vCodigos TABLE (Codigo1 varchar(50), Codigo2 varchar(50))`

**2)** Usando una tabla temporal con los mismos registros empezo a inflarse mi `temdb` aunque en menor proporcion

**3)** y usando el WITH, resulto mucho mejor y mas eficiente sin afectar el `tempdb` => `WITH tblCodigos AS (SELECT A.codigo AS Codigo1, B.codigo2)`