# ¿Qué diferencias hay entre Vistas y Tablas Temporales en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

#### ¿Qué diferencias hay entre [`Vistas`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/views.html) y [`Tablas Temporales`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) en [`MySQL`](http://dev.mysql.com/)?

Tengo mis dudas, una vez leído en la red sobre cuando debo utilizar una Vista y una Tabla Temporal. En la experiencia, he utilizado siempre *tablas temporales* juntamente a *cursores* pero nunca antes había tocado las *vistas* y veo que el comportamiento es parecido, dónde es diferente y cuándo es recomendable utilizar cada una.

Comment: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/372/diferencia-entre-variable-de-tabla-y-tabla-temporal-en-sql-server

Comment: ¿Por qué es un duplicado?¿Es una variable de tabla en MSSQL lo mismo que una vista en MySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con respecto a la primera pregunta, aquí tienes algunas diferencias importantes entre tablas temporales y vistas en MySQL:

- **Naturaleza**: una tabla temporal es una tabla, mientras que una vista es como una consulta o una macro que se realiza sobre otras tablas.
- **Persistencia**: las vistas son permanentes y seguirán existiendo de sesión en sesión, mientras que las tablas temporales desaparecerán al final de la sesión.
- **Espacio**: Una tabla temporal requiere espacio adicional, mientras que una vista no lo hace.
- **Integridad y Consistencia**: Inicialmente los había puesto separados, pero realmente están relacionados:

  - Algunas vistas se pueden actualizar y los valores que se actualizarán serán los de la tablas de origen; en cambio en una tabla temporal, sólo se actualizarán los valores de la tabla temporal.
  - Y al revés: si se actualizan los valores en las tablas que originaron la vista, los valores de la vista se actualizarán; no es el caso en las tablas temporales.
- **Rendimiento**: las vistas no van a mejorar el rendimiento de las consultas, a las tablas temporales puedes añadirles índices y claves para que sean más rápidas (aunque se pierde tiempo rellenándolas).
- **Bloqueo**: una consulta en una vista puede bloquear las tablas de origen, mientras que una tabla temporal no lo hará.

Para la segunda parte de la pregunta: ¿cuándo utilizar cada una? Va a depender mucho del uso que quieras hacer con los datos contenidos:

- Si lo que tienes es una consulta compleja pero sin mucho coste a nivel de rendimiento, elegiría una vista.
- Si la consulta es demasiado grande y compleja y los datos no entrarían en la caché, usaría una tabla temporal.
- Si se van a hacer multiples operaciones y consultas sobre los datos, usaría una tabla temporal.
- Si quieres manipular la estructura (p.e. añadir índices para que las consultas sean más rápidas), definitivamente usaría una tabla temporal.
- Si los datos en las tablas de origen no van a cambiar durante la ejecución de tu programa (o no te importa), usaría una tabla temporal (evitaría posibles bloqueos en las tablas de origen).