# Pasar datos entre vistas (Sin Entity Framework)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un formulario que en un campo tiene un botón, ese botón me abre otra vista donde tengo una lista de X cantidad de elementos. Lo que quiero hacer que al abrir esa segunda vista seleccione un elemento de la lista y esa selección se pase al textbox de la primera vista. Les agradeceré que me ayuden a como realizar esto.

Comment: Veo que estás iniciando con ASP.net MVC, hace un tiempo hice un workshop en vivo con toda la comunidad de StackOverflow en Español, aquí el video y el código fuente en la descripción: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué diferencias hay entre Vistas y Tablas Temporales en MySQL?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18154/qu%c3%a9-diferencias-hay-entre-vistas-y-tablas-temporales-en-mysql)

Comment: son temas diferentes, no es duplicado de esa pregunta mencionada

Comment: ¿Puedes por favor poner tu código? Ya que de lo contrario tendremos que cerrar la pregunta ya que no refleja ningún tipo de esfuerzo.

Comment: Te recomiendo que busques sobre el patrón de diseño observer

Comment: Solo una acotacion/pregunta al hablar de modal... Es una ventana dentro de la pagina (utilizando alguna librería tipo boostrap?) o es una ventana de navegador? Y si necesitas trabajar con info del servidor para presentar el modal? Seria mas útil que nos brindes "que información estas queriendo enviar al modal" (ejemplos... Id de cliente, nombre de producto, id de tal tabla).

Answer (score 1):

Te puede servir este articulo 
Como pasar datos entre paginas en asp.net
http://geeks.ms/fernandezja/2008/10/21/pasar-datos-entre-paginas-web-en-asp-net/

Si bien estas utilizando MVC la idea es la misma. Te puede servir el punto 4 del articulo. Pero si necesitas que dicho modal que mencionas realizar operaciones en el servidor hay que pensarlo de cargar via ajax el modal...
Si es el modo de boostrap o estas utilizando angulat ... Podríamos tener mejores arquitecturas de pasaje de datos y apertura de modales (ya que todo esta en la vista)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar Session o TempData para almacenar la info que requieres

Answer (score -1):

Crea una función. Por ejemplo:

```
function AsignarValor(cantidad) {
    $("#codigo123").val(cantidad);
}

<a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="AsignarValor('@(item("cantidad").ToString.Trim)')">Ver</a>
```

simplifique el código que genero de una tabla dinámica que lleno dependiendo de un combo.

```
<input id="codigo123" type="text" />
```