# Ya hay un objeto llamado ##TablaTemporal en la base de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado, el cual permite generar un reporte en Excel. El caso es que cuando varios usuarios están generando el reporte, aparecen una serie de errores que indican ya hay un objeto llamado `##rpttabla` en la base de datos.

Quisiera saber, ¿cómo puedo hacer para generar un nombre de tabla temporal aleatorio cada vez que se ejecuta el procedimiento?

```
IF @Opt = 0 BEGIN


    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##RptMayorD')  IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN DROP TABLE ##RptMayorD END

    --** COMPROBANTE AUTOMATICOS **--
    SELECT 
        Cuenta = D.Cuenta, 
        Descripcion=CAST('' AS VARCHAR(250)),
        Folio=CAST(A.Folio AS VARCHAR(20)), 
        Lote = CAST(A.IdLote AS VARCHAR(20)), 
        Comprobante = C.Comprobante,
        FechaContable= CONVERT(CHAR(10),F.FechaContable,103), 
        A.CodigoTransaccion, 
        ReferenciaNegocio =  C.ReferenciaNegocio, 
        OficinaTransaccion = D.OficinaContable,
        Nombre_Oficina=CAST('' AS VARCHAR(50)),
        MonedaTransaccion = c.MonedaTransaccion, 
        Cotizacion  = D.Cotizacion , 
        ValorDebito = D.ValorDebito, 
        ValorDebitoEquivalencia= D.valordebitoequivalencia,
        ValorCredito  =  D.ValorCredito, 
        ValorCreditoEquivalencia= D.ValorCreditoEquivalencia,
        Concepto=C.Concepto, 
        Observacion = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(150)),
        NroDocumento = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(15)), 
        Cliente = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(250)) ,
        a.Origen,  
        FechaTransaccion=CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.FechaTransaccion,103),
        Nombre = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(150)), 
        NombreCliente = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(150)), 
        a.IDFechaContable, 
        A.IDLote, 
        IDAsiento = C.IDAsiento,
        IDComprobante 
        INTO  ##RptMayorD
    FROM Contabilidad..Comprobante A  WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN Contabilidad..FechaContable F  WITH (NOLOCK) on F.IdFechaContable = A.IdFechaContable
    INNER JOIN GeneradorContableHistorico..Asientohistorico C  WITH (NOLOCK) on a.IdLote = c.LoteContable 
    INNER JOIN GeneradorContableHistorico..AsientoDetalleHistorico D WITH (NOLOCK) on c.IdAsiento = d.IdAsiento 
    WHERE A.EsMayorizado = 1 And A.EsCuadrado = 1 And A.EsVigente = 1 AND A.Origen <> 'MANUAL'  AND
          A.Folio LIKE @Fecha + '%'
          AND D.cuenta LIKE @Cuenta + '%' 
          AND D.Moneda LIKE  @Moneda + '%'



    --** COMPROBANTE MANUALES **--
    INSERT INTO ##RptMayorD
    SELECT 
        Cuenta = B.Cuenta, 
        Descripcion=CAST('' AS VARCHAR(250)),
        Folio=CAST(A.Folio AS VARCHAR(20)), 
        Lote = CAST(A.IdLote AS VARCHAR(20)), 
        Comprobante = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(200)), 
        FechaContable=CONVERT(CHAR(10),F.FechaContable,103), 
        A.CodigoTransaccion, 
        ReferenciaNegocio = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(250)), 
        OficinaTransaccion = B.IDOficinaContable, 
        Nombre_Oficina=CAST('' AS VARCHAR(50)),
        MonedaTransaccion = B.Moneda, 
        Cotizacion  = B.ValorCotizacion , 
        ValorDebito =B.MontoDebito, 
        ValorDebitoEquivalencia= B.MontoDebitoEquivalencia,
        ValorCredito  = B.MontoCredito, 
        ValorCreditoEquivalencia = B.MontoCreditoEquivalencia,
        Concepto= CAST(A.Comentario.query(N'/Glosa/Comentario/text()') AS VARCHAR(8000)), 
        Observacion = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(150)),
        NroDocumento = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(15)), 
        Cliente = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(250)) ,
        a.Origen,  FechaTransaccion=CONVERT(CHAR(10),
        A.FechaTransaccion,103),
        Nombre = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(150)), 
        NombreCliente = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(150)), 
        A.IDFechaContable, 
        IDLote, 
        IDAsiento = 0,A.IDComprobante
    FROM Contabilidad..Comprobante A  WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN Contabilidad..FechaContable F  WITH (NOLOCK) on F.IdFechaContable = A.IdFechaContable
    INNER JOIN Contabilidad..detallecomprobante B WITH (NOLOCK) on a.idcomprobante = b.idcomprobante 
    WHERE A.EsMayorizado = 1 And A.EsCuadrado = 1 And A.EsVigente = 1 AND A.Origen = 'MANUAL'  
            AND B.cuenta LIKE  @Cuenta + '%'  
            AND A.Folio like @Fecha + '%'
            AND B.Moneda  LIKE  @Moneda + '%'


    --> Actualizar Nombre de Oficina
    UPDATE C SET Nombre_Oficina = trx.Nombre
    FROM ##RptMayorD C  WITH (NOLOCK)
    Join Configuracion..Oficina trx  WITH (NOLOCK) on trx.idoficina = c.OficinaTransaccion

    --> Actualizar Descripcion de la Cuenta
    UPDATE C SET Descripcion = trx.Descripcion
    FROM ##RptMayorD C  WITH (NOLOCK)
    Join contabilidad..catalogocuenta trx  WITH (NOLOCK) on trx.cuenta = c.cuenta

    --> Actualizar Nombre y Numero de Documento desde cuenta cliente
    UPDATE C SET NombreCliente=Nombres, NroDocumento = Documento, Cliente=Nombres
    FROM ##RptMayorD C  WITH (NOLOCK)
    Join Cuenta..CuentaCliente Cred  WITH (NOLOCK) On Cred.NumeroCuenta = c.ReferenciaNegocio 
    Join Cliente..VW_Clientes Cli  WITH (NOLOCK) on Cred.IdCliente = Cli.IdCliente
    WHERE Origen <> 'MANUAL' 

    -->Actualizar Nombre y Numero de Documento desde credito
    UPDATE C SET NombreCliente=Nombres, NroDocumento = Documento, Cliente=Nombres
    FROM ##RptMayorD C  WITH (NOLOCK)
    Join Credito..Credito Cred  WITH (NOLOCK) On Cred.NumeroCredito = c.ReferenciaNegocio 
    Join Cliente..VW_Clientes Cli  WITH (NOLOCK) on Cred.IdCliente = Cli.IdCliente
    WHERE Origen <> 'MANUAL'  AND Cliente = ''


    --> Actualizar Nombres desde Transaccion
    UPDATE C SET Nombre=trx.Nombre, Observacion=trx.Observacion, NroDocumento = NumeroIdentificacion, Cliente = trx.Nombre
    FROM ##RptMayorD C  WITH (NOLOCK)
    Left  Join Caja..transaccion trx  WITH (NOLOCK) on trx.secuencial = c.ReferenciaNegocio 
    WHERE Origen <> 'MANUAL'  AND Cliente = ''

    UPDATE ##RptMayorD SET Nombre='' WHERE Nombre IS NULL
    UPDATE ##RptMayorD SET Observacion='' WHERE Observacion IS NULL
    UPDATE ##RptMayorD SET NombreCliente='' WHERE NombreCliente IS NULL
    UPDATE ##RptMayorD SET NroDocumento='' WHERE NroDocumento IS NULL   
    UPDATE ##RptMayorD SET Cliente='' WHERE Cliente IS NULL 

    UPDATE A SET Concepto = Concepto_A
    FROM ##RptMayorD A 
    JOIN (SELECT NumeroCuenta, ComprobanteCanal, B.IDCuentaCliente, 
                 Concepto_A=Comentario + ' ' + ComentarioEstadoCuenta, FechaContable=CONVERT(CHAR(10),C.FEchaContable,103)
          FROM Cuenta..CuentaCliente B   WITH (NOLOCK)
          JOIN Cuenta..Transaccion C  WITH (NOLOCK) ON B.IDCuentaCliente = C.IDCuentaCliente  AND C.CodigoAtributo='ATRCRECASACOMER' 
          ) D
    ON A.ReferenciaNegocio = D.NumeroCuenta AND A.CodigoTransaccion='TRANSCTA' AND A.FEchaContable = D.FEchaContable AND ComprobanteCAnal = Comprobante 


    SELECT COUNT(*) N FROM ##RptMayorD

END

IF @Opt = 1 BEGIN
    SELECT Cuenta, Descripcion, Folio, Lote, Comprobante, FechaContable, CodigoTransaccion, ReferenciaNegocio,
           Cod_Oficina = OficinaTransaccion, Nombre_Oficina, Moneda = MonedaTransaccion, Cotizacion, ValorDebito,
           ValorDebitoEquivalencia, ValorCredito, ValorCreditoEquivalencia,
           Concepto, Observacion, NroDocumento, Cliente, Origen, FechaTransaccion
    FROM ##RptMayorD
    ORDER BY Folio
END
```

La versión que utilizo es la 2012 y la tabla sólo es utilizada en ese procedimiento almacenado.

Lo que ocurre es que no puedo usar tablas temporales locales porque cada parte del procedimiento almacenado utiliza una cadena de conexión diferente (como Davlio indica en un comentario). Las tablas temporales sólo se pueden utilizar en la conexión en la que el usuario las crea. Cuando la conexión termina la tabla temporal desaparece, cuando uso tablas temporales locales me sale el error "no se encontro el objeto ****"

Comment: Me parece o estás gritando al escribir en mayúscula :)

Comment: ¿La tabla `##RptMayorD` solo se utiliza en dicho procedimiento almacenado o hay otro que lo reutiliza?. Además, sería bueno que edites tu pregunta e indiques la versión de SQL Server que estás usando.

Comment: Cecilia, bienvenida a SOes, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, luego te recomiendo que leas [ask] y como crear un [mcve]. A menos que transformes todas las sentencias del SP en queries dinámicos, no tienes formas de usar un nombre aleatorio de tabla.

Comment: Hola la Version que utilizo es la 2012 y la tabla solo es utilizada en ese procedimiento almacenado. Gracias

Comment: @CeciliaMa te invito a realizar el recorrido accediendo a https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que entiendas como funciona el sitio.

Comment: @Davlio lo que ocurre es que no puedo usar tablas temporales locales porque cada parte del sp utiliza una cadena de conexion diferente, como tu mismo indicas en tu respuesta.....
**Las tablas temporales  ... sólo se pueden utilizar en la conexión en la que el usuario las crea. Cuando la conexión termina la tabla temporal desaparece**
cuando uso tablas temporales locales me sale el error "no se encontro el objeto ****"

Comment: @CeciliaMa me das a entender que el proceso de generar tu reporte es compartida y que intervienen otras cosas, por tal motivo tu pregunta no es muy clara y no podrá ser reproducida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo Solucione Gracias.

```
declare @Cuenta Varchar(25),@Fecha Varchar(10),@Moneda Varchar(3),@User Varchar(20)
Declare @NomTabla Varchar(60)
    SET @User = 'CMARRUFO'
    SET @Cuenta ='190106010105'
    SET @Fecha ='20170812'
    SET @Moneda = 'SOL'
    SET @NomTabla = '##RptMayorDetalle' + @User



 EXEC ('IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..'+ @nomtabla + ''')  IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE '+ @nomtabla + ' END')

    --** COMPROBANTE AUTOMATICOS **--
EXEC (' SELECT 
            Cuenta = D.Cuenta, 
            Descripcion=CAST('''' AS VARCHAR(250)),
            Folio=CAST(A.Folio AS VARCHAR(20)), 
            Lote = CAST(A.IdLote AS VARCHAR(20)), 
            Comprobante = C.Comprobante,
            FechaContable= CONVERT(CHAR(10),F.FechaContable,103), 
            A.CodigoTransaccion, 
            ReferenciaNegocio =  C.ReferenciaNegocio, 
            OficinaTransaccion = D.OficinaContable,
            Nombre_Oficina=CAST('''' AS VARCHAR(50)),
            MonedaTransaccion = c.MonedaTransaccion, 
            Cotizacion  = D.Cotizacion , 
            ValorDebito = D.ValorDebito, 
            ValorCredito  =  D.ValorCredito, 
            Concepto=C.Concepto, 
            Observacion = CAST('''' AS VARCHAR(150)),
            NroDocumento = CAST('''' AS VARCHAR(15)), 
            Cliente = CAST('''' AS VARCHAR(250)) ,
            a.Origen,  
            FechaTransaccion=CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.FechaTransaccion,103),
            Nombre = CAST('''' AS VARCHAR(150)), 
            NombreCliente = CAST('''' AS VARCHAR(150)), 
            a.IDFechaContable, 
            A.IDLote, 
            IDAsiento = C.IDAsiento,
            IDComprobante 
            INTO '+ @nomtabla +'
        FROM Contabilidad..Comprobante A  WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN Contabilidad..FechaContable F  WITH (NOLOCK) on F.IdFechaContable = A.IdFechaContable
        INNER JOIN GeneradorContableHistorico..Asientohistorico C  WITH (NOLOCK) on a.IdLote = c.LoteContable 
        INNER JOIN GeneradorContableHistorico..AsientoDetalleHistorico D WITH (NOLOCK) on c.IdAsiento = d.IdAsiento 
        WHERE A.EsMayorizado = 1 And A.EsCuadrado = 1 And A.EsVigente = 1 AND A.Origen <> ''MANUAL''        
        AND A.Folio LIKE'+ @Fecha +' + ''%''
              AND D.cuenta LIKE '+ @Cuenta +' + ''%''  
              AND D.Moneda LIKE  '+ @Moneda +' + ''%''')
```

Comment: Gracias @CeciliaMa , además para que sea de ayuda a otros desarrolladores, te sugiero agregues una pequeña explicación de lo que realizaste!

Answer (score 2):

## Diferencia entre una tabla temporal global y local

> **#locales:** Las tablas temporales locales tienen una # como primer carácter en su nombre y sólo se pueden utilizar en la conexión en la
>   que el usuario las crea. Cuando la conexión termina la tabla temporal
>   desaparece.
>
> **##globales:** Las tablas temporales globales comienzan con ## y son visibles por cualquier usuario conectado al SQL Server. Y una cosa
>   más, estás tablas desaparecen cuando ningún usuario está haciendo
>   referencias a ellas, no cuando se desconecta el usuario que la creo.

---

El error que encuentras:

> ya hay un objeto llamado ##rpttabla en la base de datos

Es debido a que todo los usuarios conectados encuentran redundancia en la existencia de la tabla temporal `##rpttabla`, por ello podrías usar una tabla temporal de tipo local debido a que solo lo utilizas en un único procedimiento almacenado.

---

Podrías también considerar revisar:

- [Diferencia entre variable de tabla y tabla temporal en SQL
  Server](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/372)