# Error SQL Ya hay un objeto con el nombre

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Ya revise [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104178/ya-hay-un-objeto-llamado-tablatemporal-en-la-base-de-datos) y no es realmente lo que estoy buscando.

Veran, estoy generando un Sotred Procedure cuya consulta se convierte en un reporte de ventas.

La condicionante es, que cuando se trata de unas fechas en especifico debe seleccionar de unas tablas y si es otra fecha entonces el FROM es de otra tabla, por lo que genere el fragmento del query de esta manera:

```
IF @fecha between '2017-01-01' and '2018-06-30'
    BEGIN
        SELECT id_tienda,sum(importe) as importe 
        into #vtaAA
        FROM
        (SELECT id_tienda, 0 as importe, 0 as unidades from #tdaZona
            group by id_tienda
            UNION
            SELECT [IdTienda] as id_tienda,sum(ns) as importe, sum(qty) as unidades
            FROM dbo.BaseVentasHistoria
            where Fecha>=@fechaAnt and fecha < @fechaCAnt and idTienda in (select id_tienda from #tdaZona)
            group by idtienda) as A
        group by id_tienda
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN

        SELECT id_tienda,sum(ventas) as ventas 
        into #vtaAA
        FROM
        (SELECT id_tienda collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS as id_tienda, 0 as ventas from #tdaZona
            group by id_tienda
            UNION
            select n_tickets.id_tienda,ISNULL(sum(importeeuros),0) as ventas 
            from dbo.baseVentasDiarias with(nolock)  
            inner join n_tickets on n_tickets.id_auto = baseVentasDiarias.id_auto 
            where Fecha>=@fechaAnt and fecha < @fechaCAnt and n_tickets.id_tienda in (select id_tienda collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS as id_tienda from #tdaZona)
            group by n_tickets.id_tienda) as A
        group by id_tienda
    END
```

El tema esta, que cuando ya quiero compilar el cambio SQL me arroja estos mensajes de error

> Mens 2714, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Procedimiento alertaVta_Rockport, Línea
>   92 Ya hay un objeto con el nombre '#vtaAA' en la base de datos.

Esta es la linea 92: **into #vtaAA FROM**

> Mens 156, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Procedimiento alertaVta_Rockport, Línea 100
>   Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'as'.

Esta es la linea 100: **group by baseVentasDiarias.id_tienda) as A**

¿Alguien puede apoyarme sobre el porque marca este error? A primera mano se me ocurre que es porque #vtaAA esta en el IF y en el ELSE, pero eso no deberia ser problema porque solo se esta creando una vez segun la fecha que se recibe ¿O me equivoco?

Comment: Complementando la respuesta de @MauricioArias sugiero que leas la pregunta [Diferencia entre variable de tabla y tabla temporal en SQL Server](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/372/16841), básicamente el error que tienes se debe a que una tabla de tipo #Temp se queda almacenada físicamente y tienes que hacer el `DROP` manual, esto no sucede con la variable de tipo `TABLE` ya que su manejo en memoria es volátil y no es necesario hacer un `DROP` cada vez que ejecutes tu código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Básicamente el error que tienes se debe a que una tabla de tipo
>   `#Temp` se queda almacenada físicamente y tienes que hacer el `DROP`
>   manual, esto no sucede con la variable de tipo `TABLE` ya que su
>   manejo en memoria es volátil y no es necesario hacer un DROP cada vez
>   que ejecutes tu código.

**Fuente: Aporte del usuario [Flxtr](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16841/flxtr) en su [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/112579/error-sql-ya-hay-un-objeto-con-el-nombre/112583?noredirect=1#comment208700_112579).**

---

Una alternativa para solucionar este error podría ser:

- Crear una variable de tipo `TABLE`.

He modificado tu código con mi sugerencia:

```
DECLARE @TablaResultado AS TABLE (
    idTienda AS INT,
    importe AS FLOAT
);

IF @fecha between '2017-01-01' and '2018-06-30'
    BEGIN   
        INSERT INTO @TablaResultado
        SELECT id_tienda,sum(importe) as importe
        FROM
        (SELECT id_tienda, 0 as importe, 0 as unidades from #tdaZona
            group by id_tienda
            UNION
            SELECT [IdTienda] as id_tienda,sum(ns) as importe, sum(qty) as unidades
            FROM dbo.BaseVentasHistoria
            where Fecha>=@fechaAnt and fecha < @fechaCAnt and idTienda in (select id_tienda from #tdaZona)
            group by idtienda) as A
        group by id_tienda;
    END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @TablaResultado
    SELECT id_tienda,sum(ventas) as ventas
    FROM
    (SELECT id_tienda collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS as id_tienda, 0 as ventas from #tdaZona
        group by id_tienda
        UNION
        select n_tickets.id_tienda,ISNULL(sum(importeeuros),0) as ventas 
        from dbo.baseVentasDiarias with(nolock)  
        inner join n_tickets on n_tickets.id_auto = baseVentasDiarias.id_auto 
        where Fecha>=@fechaAnt and fecha < @fechaCAnt and n_tickets.id_tienda in (select id_tienda collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS as id_tienda from #tdaZona)
        group by n_tickets.id_tienda) as A
    group by id_tienda
END

-- Cuando se ejecute tu procedimiento almacenado,
-- Los resultados estarán en esta variable.
SELECT * FROM @TablaResultado
```

Comment: Aparentemente todo fue por que tenia el mismo nombre de tabla temporal en el IF y en el ELSE, hice una prueba cambiando el nombre en el ELSE y ya pudo compilar el SP, pero marco tu respuesta porque es un metodo mucho mas limpio y práctico que andar rastreando nombres. Gracias!

Comment: @RodrigoJimenez con gusto, el [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/112579/error-sql-ya-hay-un-objeto-con-el-nombre/112583?noredirect=1#comment208700_112579) que hace el usuario Flxtr es correcto. Lo agregaré a la respuesta para futuras referencias.

Answer (score 1):

Rodrigo, conceptualmente un `SELECT * INTO tabla` es un `CREATE TABLE ...` + `INSERT INTO ...`. En tu Sp tienes dos de estas sentencias que apuntan a la misma tabla `#vtaAA` por lo que el motor al compilar te da un error en el segundo `SELECT * INTO tabla`, por que "interpreta" que estás creando dos veces la misma tabla. Es como hacer esto:

```
create table #T(id int)
create table #T(id int)
```

El error obtenido es similar al tuyo y por supuesto no se llega a crear la tabla `#T`. La solución es reemplazar los `SELECT * INTO` por un `CREATE TABLE` y luego unos clásicos `INSERT INTO`.

```
create table #T(id int)

if <condicion> begin
   insert into #t (id)
   select id
          from tabla1
end else begin
   insert into #t (id)
   select id
          from tabla2
end
```