# consulta a tres tablas con INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

Hola chicos el problema que tengo es el siguiente, tengo tres tablas "post", "copias" "Amigos" relacionadas entre si. les explico en la tabla **AMIGOS** se guardan los id de sesiones de los amigos entre si , en la tabla post se guarda la información de los que publiquen un post por ejemplo su nombre apellido etc... .después que el usuario publique un post hay una opción o un botón que al pulsar la función que hara es sacar una copia de el post deseado y se guardara la información  en la tabla **Copias** básicamente la misma información por que en realidad es una copia del post lo que se guardara, lo único que va a variar sera la **fecha** . Bien hasta ahí todo bien, ahora lo que yo necesito realmente es leer esas dos tablas mediante una query que me muestre todo el contenido de la tabla POST y COPIAS por orden de fecha no se si me doy a entender ,aquí les dejo un ejemplo:

**NOTA**:esta consulta es exitosa me muestra todo el contenido de las dos tablas de los usuarios que son mis amigos pero quiero que me la muestre por orden de fecha ya que me esta mostrando todo desorganizado.

```
SELECT * FROM
         amigos a LEFT JOIN 
         contenido ON  contenido.id_user = a.para
         LEFT JOIN copias 
         ON contenido.id = copias.post_id  and copias.id_user = a.para
         WHERE  de='{$_SESSION["id"]}'



        tabla "Amigos"


        ---------|--------|---------|-----------|
         id_ami  | de     |para     |fecha      |
        ---------|--------|---------|-----------|


        tabla "Post"

        ---------|--------|---------|-----------|--------|------|
         id_post | Nombre |Apellido |Comentario |Imagen  |Fecha |
        ---------|--------|---------|-----------|--------|------|



        tabla "Copias"

        ---------|--------|---------|-----------|-----------|-------|------|
         id_cop  |id_post |Nombre   |Apellido   |Comentario |Imagen |fecha |
        ---------|--------|---------|-----------|-----------|-------|------|
```

Ojala y me puedan ayudar de como podrías ordenarla por fecha gracias!!

Comment: Porque no agregas `ORDER BY a.fecha`

Comment: pero esa es la tabla amigos, no sera `ORDER BY contenido.fecha` si es eso ya lo intente y no funciono

Comment: @andygibbs, intentaste `copias.fecha` o `contenido.fecha`? suponiendo que `contenido` es la tabla `post`.

Comment: Porque no intentas `ORDER BY contenido.fecha DESC`

Comment: si lo siento es que se me olvido que le cambie el nombre a la tabla post a contenido , pero bueno es realidad entiendes lo que quiero ?

Comment: @andygibbs mas o menos, ¿intentase lo que de mencioné en el comentario?. Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta colocando cómo sería un ejemplo de la respuesta que esperas obtener (y si es posible, datos).

Comment: lo intentare ya te cuento como me fue, mi pregunta seria y que pasara con la fecha de copias ya que si le digo `ORDER BY contenido.fecha DESC` no me tendria en cuenta la fecha de la tabla copias?

Comment: ¿Cuál de las tres fechas?

Comment: cual de las tres fechas que? @rubench0

Comment: @andygibbs creo que se refiere a esta parte: `una query que me muestre todo el contenido de la tabla POST y COPIAS por orden de fecha` = ¿por cuál fecha?

Comment: eso es lo que no se exactamente por que lo que lo que necesito hacer es que me muestre todo de las dos tablas en orden, que si yo publico un post ejemplo ahora en la tabla post me salga ese pos de primero y si publico un post en la tabla copias ahora mismo que ese me salga de primero y el post de la tablas post pase abajo , me doy a entender?

Comment: @andygibbs, bueno, yo la verdad se algo de SQL, por lo que no se si en MySql puedes usar variables de tipo `TABLE`. Voy a colocar una respuesta con un pseudo-código para dar a entender lo que expongo en este comentario.

Comment: vale te entiendo pero espero que entiendas a lo que me refiero ,te voy a poner un ejemplo de esta misma pagina vamos a suponer que las preguntas de stack over flow con las etiquetas ,php,javascript y mysql son tres tablas diferentes y cada ves que una persona hace una pregunta con la etiqueta php se guarda en la tabla php, y el que hace una pregunta con la etiqueta javascript se guarda en la tabla javascript, etc... como veras no importa en que tabla las preguntas siempre se muestran en orden una debajo de otra por fecha es lo que quiero hacer algo similar

Comment: Andy, no entiendo bien la especie de lío que tienes en tu diseño. Si me aceptas una opinión, me parece que cuando hay que recurrir a cosas algo extrañas para obtener nuestros resultados es probable que haya que repensar el modelo de datos. En cuanto la pregunta en sí, he podido entender que quieres una especie de orden que compare cual es el mayor o el menor entre dos columnas fecha de dos tablas distintas. En MySQL existe para ello la función `GREATEST` que te devuelve el valor mayor entre dos columnas, o su  hermana `LEAST` que hace lo contrario...

Comment: ... puedes usarla en el orden haciendo algo como `... ORDER BY GREATEST(t1.fecha, t2.fecha) `. Aquí puedes ver la referencia en la documentación:  para [**`GREATEST`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)  y para [**`LEAST`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)

Answer (score 3):

Si he entendido bien, quieres ordenar comparando siempre dos fechas provenientes de dos tablas distintas que participan en el `JOIN`.

Para ello MySQL cuenta con las funciones `LEAST` y `GREATEST`.

> ### `LEAST()`
>
> Con dos o más argumentos, devuelve el argumento más pequeño (valor mínimo). Los argumentos se comparan utilizando las
>   siguientes reglas:
>
> - Si algún argumento es `NULL`, el resultado es `NULL`. No se necesita ninguna comparación.
> - Si todos los argumentos tienen valores enteros, se comparan como enteros.
> - Si al menos un argumento es de doble precisión, se comparan como valores de precisión doble. De lo contrario, si al menos un argumento
>     es un valor `DECIMAL`, se comparan como valores `DECIMAL`.
> - Si los argumentos comprenden una combinación de números y cadenas, se comparan como números.
> - Si cualquier argumento es una cadena no binaria (carácter), los argumentos se comparan como cadenas no binarias.
> - En todos los demás casos, los argumentos se comparan como cadenas binarias.
> - El tipo de devolución de `LEAST()` es el tipo agregado de los tipos de argumentos de comparación.
>
> <sub>- [`LEAST()` en la documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)</sub>

---

> ### `GREATEST`
>
> Con dos o más argumentos, devuelve el argumento más grande (valor máximo). Los argumentos se comparan utilizando las
>   mismas reglas que para `LEAST()`.
>
> <sub>- [`GREATEST()` en la documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)</sub>

---

### Aplicación

Ambas funciones se pueden aplicar para ordenar los datos en combinación con `ORDER BY`. Además, nótese que se puede usar varias columnas o valores en la comparación, como hemos leído más arriba.

En una prueba de concepto, la ordenación usando `GREATEST` sería algo así:

```
/*Ordenar por la mayor entre las dos columnas*/
SELECT 
    *
FROM posts_20180724 p
    INNER JOIN copia_20180724 c ON p.post_id=c.post_id
ORDER BY GREATEST(p.post_date,c.copy_date);
```

**Salida:**

```
post_id      post_title      post_date             copy_id    copy_date
    1        Post1           01.07.2017 00:00:00    1         02.07.2017 00:00:00
    2        Post2           02.07.2017 00:00:00    2         03.07.2017 00:00:00
    4        Post4           04.07.2017 00:00:00    4         01.03.2017 00:00:00
    3        Post3           03.07.2017 00:00:00    3         04.07.2017 00:00:00
```

Y usando `LEAST` sería algo así:

```
/*Ordenar por la menor entre las dos columnas*/
SELECT 
    *
FROM posts_20180724 p
    INNER JOIN copia_20180724 c ON p.post_id=c.post_id
ORDER BY LEAST(p.post_date,c.copy_date);
```

**Salida:**

```
post_id     post_title      post_date             copy_id   copy_date
4           Post4           04.07.2017 00:00:00    4        01.03.2017 00:00:00
1           Post1           01.07.2017 00:00:00    1        02.07.2017 00:00:00
2           Post2           02.07.2017 00:00:00    2        03.07.2017 00:00:00
3           Post3           03.07.2017 00:00:00    3        04.07.2017 00:00:00
```

---

#### Ver Demo

Aquí puedes ver una <kbd>**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/JVM57784)**</kbd> usando datos reales y puedes hacer pruebas.

Espero sea de utilidad.

Comment: Genial amigo tu ejemplo ya estoy checkando la documentacion , una pregunta a tu respuesta seria como leer las tablas en dado caso ?  me refiero a la hora de ejecutar el while  para extraer los datos . perdon por la ignorancia , no soy tan experto en estos temas de sql

Comment: @andygibbs no entendí lo que me preguntas en tu comentario... si me lo aclaras y no es tema para desarrollarlo en otra pregunta con gusto te responderé si está a mi alcance.

Comment: tratare de darme a entender , quiero decir despues de la centencia sql `SELECT 
    *
FROM posts_20180724 p
    INNER JOIN copia_20180724 c ON p.post_id=c.post_id
ORDER BY LEAST(p.post_date,c.copy_date);` siempre leo los datos con un while dependiendo  es decir a la hora de yo ejecutar el while en este caso para mostrar el contenido por orden de fecha de las dos tablas como seria ?

Comment: @andygibbs el contenido ya viene ordenado, solamente tienes que leer las columnas que necesites dentro del `while` como haces habitualmente. **OJO**: Aquí yo he puesto `SELECT *  ...`, el asterisco indica que traiga todas las columnas de todas las tablas. Lo he hecho así por simplicidad, lo correcto sería que pusieras las columnas que necesitas en el `SELECT` y luego imprimas los datos de esas columnas dentro del  `while`

Answer (score 1):

Si he entendido bien lo que expones en los comentarios de tu pregunta *(que por cierto, deben estar realmente en la pregunta y no en los comentarios)*<sup>1</sup> te propongo esto:

- Crear una variable de tipo `TABLE` la cual tendrá la información de las tablas `POST` y `COPIAS`.
- Modificar la consulta que tienes para que apunte a esta variable de tipo `TABLE` para traer por orden de fecha los posts/copias realizadas en ambas tablas.

Este es un pseudo-código que ilustra mejor lo expuesto en los anteriores puntos:

```
// Esta variable de tipo TABLE guardará todos los registros de la tabla POST y COPIAS.
DECLARE @tablaResultados AS TABLE
(
     Nombre NVARCHAR(255),
     Apellido NVARCHAR(255),
     Comentario NVARCHAR(255),
     Imagen NVARCHAR(255),
     Fecha DATETIME
)

// Primero, inserto los datos de la tabla POST en la variable de tipo TABLE llamada @tablaResultados:
INSERT INTO @tablaResultado (Nombre, Apellido, Comentario, Imagen, Fecha)
SELECT Nombre, Apellido, Comentario, Imagen, Fecha
FROM POST;

// Luego inserto los datos de la tabla COPIAS en la variable de tipo TABLE llamada @tablaResultados:
INSERT INTO @tablaResultado (Nombre, Apellido, Comentario, Imagen, Fecha)
SELECT Nombre, Apellido, Comentario, Imagen, Fecha
FROM COPIAS;

// Ya luego tu consulta sería así:
// La consulta obtiene los resultados de ambas tablas "POST" y "COPIAS" ordenados por fecha (descendente) = el registro mas reciente se mostrará en primer lugar.
SELECT Nombre, Apellido, Comentario, Imagen, Fecha
FROM @tablaResultado
ORDER BY Fecha DESC;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Los comentarios en las preguntas / respuestas son temporales, en cualquier momento serán eliminados.

Comment: wuao tu respuesta esta interesante e  intrigante man ,pero a cinceridad nunca havia escuchado de ese tipo de variables " TABLE "  puedes porfavor si no es mucha molestia darme una breve explicacion de que son y como funcionan voy a votar por tu respuesta por que la verdad se ve muy logica a lo que nececito hacer

Comment: @andygibbs no soy muy bueno explicando - lo aprendí con la práctica y gracias a Stack Overflow en Español. Te remito a esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/372/78) - *enfocada en SQL Server*. Honestamente no tengo tanta experiencia en MySQL por lo que te recomiendo consultar con alguien que sepa de MySQL. Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo es un tema que lo tendre que estudiar profundamente